Logging stopped working for no apparent reason
I'm using log4net on my WPF app and it worked well for quite some time but I noticed that recently it didn't log anything anymore.
[EDIT] By that I mean no new file is created and no logs are shown in the Visual Studio output (it was before).
At first I thought it was because I upgraded my project to .NET 8 but there are logs in the .\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows7.0\logs folder. It stopped around July 24th but I have logs dating early March.
I didn't modify anything in my project properties (.csproj), assembly file, log4net config file, app file or anything of sort. And when I say anything, it means nothing; even thing unrelated to log4net. I didn't even change any logger as it worked as I wanted and I didn't need to change it.
I'm using VS2022 Community v17.11.0 on Windows 10
I tried to upgrade log4net from v2.0.15 to 2.0.17 but it didn't change anything.
The logging doesn't work either in Debug or Release.
My App.config contains
<log4net configSource="Log4net.config"/>
and
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="false"/>
</appSettings>

and appsettings.json contains
{
  "log4net.Internal.Debug": false
}

I did try to change it to true (one at a time or both together) but it didn't fix my problem.
My log4net.config file is set to "Copy always"
My AssemblyInfo.cs contains
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
Finally here's my log4net config file (even if I doubt it comes from here).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="AppRollingFileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AppDebugRollingFileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AppDebugAppender"/>
    </root>

    <appender name="AppRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs\cvla_.log"/>
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level %-15logger %message %newline"/>
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="INFO"/>
            <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AppDebugRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs\cvla_.log"/>
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_debug'"/>
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %-15logger %message %newline"/>
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
            <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AppDebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %-15logger %message %newline"/>
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
            <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    
    <logger name="CalculationLogger" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CalculationRollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <appender name="CalculationRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs\cvla_.log"/>
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
        <!--
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs\%date{yyyy_MM_dd}-cvla_calculation.log" />
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="false"/>
        -->
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_calculation'"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %message %newline"/>
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
            <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>
</log4net>

Has anyone had the same problem? Is it a log4net problem or something Microsoft modified in some updates?
[UPDATE]
Following advices I enabled internal logging and use DebugView but nothing is displayed. I also tried to push the traces to a file following the troobleshooting problems section of this site but no file is created (I made sure the target folder was in a place where it could be written to without special permissions).
[UPDATE 2]
From other tests it may be a localized problem. I have the exact same code (through git) running on another computer and the logging seems to work there.
It doesn't work anymore just like on my first computer.

What do you mean by it didn't log anything anymore? Are the files empty or are there no (new) files at all? If you did not change anything, you could look into something locking the file (system) like a virus scanner or something.

No new files are made and nothing is logged in the output either.
The windows security in the folders in which it supposed to be added isn't protected and if it was only that, the logs in the VS output would most likely work.

Setting log4net.Internal.Debug to true never fixes any problems, but it may output some debug messages to tell you what is wrong. If you are running inside VS, the messages may appear there, otherwise you can see them in DebugView (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview )

Another vote for enabling internal logging. Check out the 'Troubleshooting problems' section here: https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/

Thanks for the advices. Your propositions unfortunately didn't work. I updated the original post with my tests and findings (or lack thereof)


"log4net.Internal.Debug": false . I think the value needs to be quoted, so if your application is using appsettings.json then this should be "log4net.Internal.Debug": "true" to enable logging. If that does not work, then add log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true; to your program


Out of curiosity, do you see anything relevant in the Windows Event Logs around the time it stopped? e.g. a Disk Full error? application crash? did someone try to start multiple instances and they both tried to use the exact same log filenames? etc?
